# Is there any pattern to the Spider Queen's movements?

Tags: dont-starve

I witnessed the birth of a Spider Queen ridiculously close to my base. I managed to come back later and she'd wandered off, but then she wandered back a few days later so I ran off again. Does she stay in a given area? Wander the whole map at random? Will she vanish after a while or stay on the map permanently? (I died before seeing her a third time)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

She should despawn into a tier 1 nest after a day and a half, according to the wiki. Based on my observations, it seems like she just picks a direction and continues on that general path unless there's something to attack.

Answer (score 0):

In the newer version (from what I have experienced) the queen doesn't despawn and will stay around were the nest was and wander in a proximity of it, she will also hatch spiders.